# What is the purpose of clojure.core.reducers/reduce?

Tags: clojure

A slightly modified version of [`reduce`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/reduce) was introduced with [*reducers*](http://clojure.org/reference/reducers), [`clojure.core.reducers/reduce`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core.reducers/reduce) (short `r/reduce`):

```
(defn reduce
  ([f coll]
   (reduce f (f) coll))
  ([f init coll]
   (if (instance? java.util.Map coll)
     (clojure.core.protocols/kv-reduce coll f init)
     (clojure.core.protocols/coll-reduce coll f init))))
```

`r/reduce` differs from its core sibling only in that it uses `(f)` as the initial value when none is provided, and it delegates to core `reduce-kv` for maps.

I don’t understand what use such an odd special-purpose `reduce` might be and why it was worth including in the reducers library.

Curiously, `r/reduce` is not mentioned in the two introductory blog posts as far as I can tell ([first](http://clojure.com/blog/2012/05/08/reducers-a-library-and-model-for-collection-processing.html), [second](http://clojure.com/blog/2012/05/15/anatomy-of-reducer.html)). The official documentation notes

> In general most users will not call r/reduce directly and instead should prefer r/fold (...) However, it may be useful to execute an eager reduce with fewer intermediate results.

I’m unsure what that last sentence hints at.

What situations can `r/reduce` handle that the core reduces cannot? When would I reach for `r/reduce` with conviction?

Comment: It seems that the differences you mentioned (using reducing function to produce init value and using reduce-kv for maps) are the only ones. I think we can speculate that using a specialized version for maps avoids allocation overhead as each map entry doesn't have to be wrapped into a 2-element vector but it's instead passed directly as separate arguments to reducing function.

Answer (score 3):

Two possible reasons:

1. **It has different – better! – semantics than `clojure.core/reduce` in the initless sequential case.** During his 2014 Conj presentation Rich Hickey asked "who knows what the semantics of `reduce` are when you call it with a collection and no initial value?" – [follow this link for the exact spot in the presentation](https://youtu.be/4KqUvG8HPYo?t=1769) – and then described the said semantics as "a ridiculous, complex rule" and "one of the worst things [he] ever copied from Common Lisp" – cf. [Common Lisp's `reduce` contract](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_reduce.htm). The presentation was about transducers and the context of the remark was a discussion of `transduce`, which has a superior, simpler contract; `r/reduce` does as well.
2. Even without considering the above, **it's sort of nice to have a version of `reduce` with a contract very close to that of `fold`.** That enables simple "try one, try the other" benchmarking with the same arguments, as well as simply changing one's mind.